# Botium isn't working following the tutorial

Tags: testing, chatbot, ibm-watson

I'm setting up Botium testing freamework to run some tests against my watson based chatbot, I'm encountering Error: WATSON_USER capability required, I'm follwoing the tutorial available here https://chatbotsmagazine.com/10-minutes-codeless-test-automation-for-ibm-watson-chatbots-d71eac9626d7

As part of the error message, it's also suggesting me to use API key, I'm not sure how to get one.

```
botium-cli emulator --config ./botium.json
Error: WATSON_USER capability required (or use WATSON_APIKEY)
    at BotiumConnectorWatson.Validate (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/botium-cli/node_modules/botium-connector-watson/dist/botium-connector-watson-cjs.js:60:55)
    at Validate.Validate.then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/botium-cli/node_modules/botium-core/src/containers/PluginConnectorContainer.js:72:66)
```

My config looks like:

```json
{
    "botium": {
        "Capabilities": {
            "PROJECTNAME": "****",
            "CONTAINERMODE": "watson",
            "WATSONCONVERSATION_USER": "*****",
            "WATSONCONVERSATION_PASSWORD": "*****",
            "WATSONCONVERSATION_WORKSPACE_ID": "****",
            "WATSONCONVERSATION_USE_INTENT": false
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The capability names in Botium have changed a while ago, you can find documentation on the valid capabilities for the Botium Watson Connector on Github: https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-watson

I updated the article you mentioned with the new capability names. The botium.json should look like this (see article):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, it worked!!!, however I'm facing another issue while testing the intents, we have dialogues  in watson, they aren't just intents.  I'm getting follwoing error, is this a standard error or is something wrong? ```hi
BOT SAYS (default): Hey. I’m Ned!
I’m an AI bot who is learning to chat, so go easy on me 
BOT SAYS (default): How are you?
good
(node:30206) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Got duplicate intent confidence { intent: 'binary_response_positive', confidence: 1 } vs { intent: 'mood_good', confidence: 1 }
```

Comment: This is actually a feature in Botium: as soon as it finds two intents with exactly the same confidence, it is considered as failed test.

Comment: How can we output `botium-cli run --config ./botium.json` result to JSON/XML as described in that article? do I need to use Mocha or Botium itself can output in visual UI?

Comment: `botium-cli run xunit ...` or `botium-cli run json ...` to output in junit-xml or json. use `botium-cli run --help` to show the output format options (xml, text, html, csv, ...)

Answer (score 0):

The error message most likely refers to you requiring a valid username/password (process has changed).

Your IBM cloud username /password is not used for this. When you created the Watson Assistant resource it creates a default credentials for that resource.

At your Watson Assistant skill, select the menu (instead of going into it) and select "View API details".

You will find the IAM apikey. If you have a much earlier instance, it will have username password.

I am not familar with botim, but if it does not have the option to send an API key, then send the username "apikey" and the api key as the password.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm actually working on Botium, I needed specifics related to Botium, but Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ok, but to clarify does the connection work with your credentials if you use say CURL? You can rule out the authentication issue, as that is what the error is hinting toward.

Comment: Its working fine with the above credentials that I've mentioned, Watson may be providing backward compatibility. Error was due to the syntax of Botium, I was not following latest documentation.

Comment: @epsan ok awesome :)